# Search and Replace a word within a word in Python. Replace() method not working

Tags: python

How do I search and replace using built-in Python methods?

For instance, with a string of appleorangegrapes (yes all of them joined),
Replace "apple" with "mango".

The .replace method only works if the words are evenly spaced out but not if they are combined as one. Is there a way around this?

I searched the web but again the .replace method only gives me an example if they are spaced out.

Thank you for looking at the problem!

Comment: *"The .replace method only works if the words are evenly spaced out"* what makes you think that?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Exactly :-)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here you can ① post your code (as a [mcve]), ② describe what you observe it does (with which input), and ③ describe what you expect to observe instead.  This results in a clear question which can be answered.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works exactly as expected and advertised. Have a look:

```
s = 'appleorangegrapes'
print(s)  # -> appleorangegrapes
s = s.replace('apple', 'mango')
print(s)  # -> mangoorangegrapes
```

---

The only thing that you have to be careful of is that `replace` is not an **in-place** operator and as such it does not update `s` automatically; it only creates a new string that you have to assign to something.

```
s = 'appleorangegrapes'
s.replace('apple', 'mango')  # the change is made but not saved
print(s)  # -> appleorangegrapes
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess what I missed out is the replace method being an in-place operator. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`replace` can work for any string, why you think that it doesn't, here is the test:

```
>>> s='appleorangegrapes'
>>> s.replace('apple','mango')
'mangoorangegrapes'
>>>
```

Don't you see that you received your expected result?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess what I missed out is the replace method being an in-place operator. Thanks again!